# why block height is missing in my transaction?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

https://testnet.blockchain.info/rawaddr/mxv7yTUcfiEoGG2Rc63wKrrVDPtrZKSZFq

i am using api call to get transaction details of my address incoming and outgoing. for some addresses i am getting block_height and for few address i am not getting block height., May I know why this issue is coming and what will be reason for this. baSed on block_height i am getting confimation count without block height I cannot make transaction as confirmed.

https://testnet.blockchain.info/rawaddr/mq9C65MzSxuJPRUmvQBE6CqbsBMnfj2rEG

this results with block_height.Please give me solution for this issue. Thanks in advance.